# How to make my application as a trial version?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i want to make my application trial version for certain time to used for my customer. so i also have dll file downloaded. then what is the process to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These links may help you

http://www.softwarekey.com/swk_products/trial_creator/

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=319168

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply license on your application and you have to store data in your database or in your application related to expiry date.

this thing you require to code.

there are no of example avaiable on google related to licensing your application for given no. of days.